# Facebook API Documentation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook provides an endpoint to get an access token given an authentication code:

`/oauth/access_token?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&code={code}`

Where can I find an example response for this endpoint? I've searched for two days without finding a single example response for this API.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: Heh, thanks. It would be nice if they put it with the rest of the graph APIs.